# How to update jquery-mobile files in my app?

Tags: jquery, xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to update jquery-mobile files in my app. I am developing the app using phonegap and jquery-mobile. My code includes RC3 jquery mobile files. Now, if i replace the jquery-mobile rc3 files with latest 1.0 files, my app doesn't look same as before. 
How can i update files without any changes in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see breaking change  from rc3 to 1.0 http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/#upgrade
What does it mean that the application looks different?
Try change theme.